# p value and hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

In a random sample of 99 games the home team won 57 games. Test the null hypothesis That home team wins one half of all games against the alternative that the home team wins a majority games.

How can I calculate p value and find the threshold of significance level??

Do I reject the null hypothesis(H0) if p-P/root(p(1-p)/n) > Zp

So that p value is P(Zp> )?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by p, P, n and Zp. But you should probably use a binomial test

Answer (score 0):

You have

$H_0: p=0.5$

$H_A: p > 0.5$

$T=\frac{\frac{57}{99}-0.5}{\sqrt{0.5\cdot 0.5}}\cdot \sqrt{99}$

If $|T|>z_{1-\alpha }$, then you reject $H_0$.

$\alpha$ is the significance level.

The value of $z_{1-\alpha }=z_p$ can be found at a table of the standard normal distribution, e.g [here](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf)